# Reading property file in Spring MVC app

Tags: spring

I'm trying to read a property file using below code, basically I'm having a Spring Boot app and I'm trying to read the below non spring bean class.The property file is in src/main/resource directory.

```
public class VisaProperties {

    static Properties properties;

    static {
        try {
            properties = new Properties();
            String propertiesFile = System.getProperty("ftproperties");
            if (propertiesFile == null) {
                properties.load(VisaProperties.class.getResourceAsStream("motoconfig.cybersource.properties"));
            } else {
                properties.load(new FileReader(propertiesFile));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static String getProperty(Property property) {
        return (String) properties.get(property.getValue());
    }
}
```

and trying call the end point property using below code getting null. How can I call the property?

```
VisaProperties.getProperty(Property.END_POINT)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done, using the code below:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
            InputStream inputStream = VisaProperties.class
                    .getClassLoader()
                    .getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
            properties.load(inputStream);
            inputStream.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the code as:

```
final Properties properties = new Properties();
try (final InputStream stream =
       this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("config.properties")) {
       properties.load(stream);
}
```

> **Note:** Use "try with resources" so that stream will be automatically
>   closed when the try {} block exits.